# .htaccess not working under WAMP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory located in F:/wamp/www/proto and the structure is the following

- admin
- class
- functions
- img
- public
- style
- .htaccess

My .htaccess contains

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  /proto/public/index.php     /proto/public/indexx.php
```

(For a simple test)

The `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is uncommented in httpd.conf

I restarted WAMP and I can access to `local/proto/public/index.php` but can not access to `local/proto/public/indexx.php`

I also tried to put .htaccess in public folder but nothing changed, error 404

Is my .htaccess in the wrong place ? Should I edit something else in Apache ?

Comment: You probably miss `AllowOverride` directive in your apache configuration (httpd.conf) for the directory where .htaccess is.

Comment: Do both `index.php` and `indexx.php` exist ? Actually, do you want to access `index.php` (without changing it in the browser address bar) and see the content of `indexx.php` ? Or the opposite ?

Comment: @astax I have `AllowOverride` everywhere needed and also `Require all granted`
@JustinIurman I have an index.php and I want to display it when I use indexx.php, so the opposite of what you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your htaccess is in `proto` folder, `RewriteRule` will erase everything before `public` in this case (per-directory context). So you're trying to match an incorrect path.

You can replace your current code by this one

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /proto/

RewriteRule ^public/indexx\.php$ public/index.php [L]
```

Now `local/proto/public/indexx.php` will internally rewrite to (= display the same content as) `local/proto/public/index.php`